# Is there an easier way to use Firebase in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, firebase, firebase-authentication

My company makes software that begins its workflow on a Windows desktop, then has the option to push data to a Windows Mobile device. I have been tasked with creating an Android version of the mobile software, and have decided that Firebase looks about perfect for what we need, which is a cloud repository for data that needs to make its way from the desktop to the mobile device.

The Firebase Real-Time Database looks like it will be easy(?) enough to use from the desktop, because it supplies a REST API; however, we also need Authentication, which appears that the only SDK option available would be wrapping javascript inside a web page embedded within the application.

I have started figuring out how to do this, but while I am searching for the how-to's, I was wondering:

1. Will this ultimately be a good solution? (Okay, that's kind of vague, I know, so feel free to ignore it in favor of my real question)
2. Am I missing an easier (or just any other) way to authenticate users in Firebase from Visual Basic .NET than wrapping a web app? I would prefer to leave login sources up to the user, which is why I want Firebase, but letting them have unrestricted access to the whole database, including other users' data, is right out. And I'm not seeing any other way to authenticate users with Firebase that will be compatible with VB.NET.

Comment: Since Firebase doesn't have a .NET SDK, you cannot use that for authentication. This [Firebase documentation page explains custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#top_of_page) pretty well. Authentication on Android can use may different providers, all documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users). I'm not really clear how you're trying to mix both in this question.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I need to do research on JSON Web Tokens. My understanding of Firebase Authentication is that it automates a bunch of stuff for multiple authentication sources (Google profiles, Facebook, etc) that I don't yet fully understand and was hoping I would be able to pick up as I go. My ultimate goal with the authentication is to get the billing handled as painlessly as possible, and to allow a customer to specify child accounts for employees that are allowed to access the company data, which the description of being able to specify groups in Firebase seems to provide.

Comment: The fact that I can use another source for authentication does open up a lot of possibilities I'll have to start searching for, though; thank you.